# User signatures are not showing up in comments

Tags: comments

User signatures are not showing up in comments.

Drupal version is 7.41

In /admin/structure/types/manage/forum/comment/display the setting "User signature" is set to visible.

In comment.tpl.php:

```
<?php if ($signature): ?>
<div class="user-signature clearfix">
  <?php print $signature ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In advanced-forum.themename.post.tpl.php

```
  <?php if (!empty($signature)): ?>
    <div class="author-signature">
      <?php print $signature ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

But user signature is not shown neither in forum or other node comments.

I've checked the generated html code and it is not a css issue. I've disabled advanced forum and I've also used the Garland theme, but the issue persists.

What can I do to have the user signatures shown?

Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using `<?php   
      $comment_author = user_load($comment->uid);
      $fsignature = $comment_author->signature;
      print ($fsignature);
?>`